# Error in copying artifact between pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am playing around with Jenkins with some sample codes I found and I'm having problems in artifact copying (I think). So I'm running Jenkins in a Docker on my Windows 11 machine. In Jenkins, there's a simple flow of pipelines (`build_pipeline`, `test_pipeline` & `deploy_pipeline`) which all of this will run in sequence. So `build_pipeline` just fetches the codes from GitHub and builds it, then `test_pipeline` will do some basic unit testing, and finally `deploy_pipeline` will deploy the new updated code. I'm having an error during the `deploy_pipeline` phase:

This is my `build_pipeline` script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:2-alpine'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py'
                stash(name: 'compiled-results', includes: 'sources/*.py*')
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'sources/*.py*', fingerprint: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the deploy_pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        VOLUME = '$(pwd)/sources:/src'
        IMAGE = 'cdrx/pyinstaller-linux:python2'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Deliver') {
            steps {
                // Copy the artifacts from the Build pipeline
                copyArtifacts projectName: 'build_pipeline', filter: 'compiled-results', selector: specific('lastSuccessful')

                // Unstash the 'compiled-results' stash
                unstash name: 'compiled-results'

                dir(path: env.BUILD_ID) {
                    sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'pyinstaller -F add2vals.py'"
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts "${env.BUILD_ID}/sources/dist/add2vals"
                    sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'rm -rf build dist'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

During the `deploy_pipeline` phase, this error will occur:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/deploy_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deliver)
[Pipeline] copyArtifacts
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: build_pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```

I already ticked the "Allow to copy artifacts" in the configuration for `build_pipeline` so I'm not sure what else is wrong here. No problem with `test_pipeline`. Just `deploy_pipeline` since it needs to reuse the stash saved in the `build_pipeline`, but for some reason it cannot find the stash. Any guidance/help is greatly appreciated.